# Using a Redis Singleton for NextJS API Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redis, next.js, ioredis

In my NextJS app, I have multiple API routes:

- /api/user/[id]
- /api/questions
- /api/posts

Each of these endpoints uses a Redis connection to `get` or `put` data within a Redis server.

I've noticed that I get errors in my console, because I am making too many connections to the Redis server. So I had an idea of creating a Singleton class and connecting to the Redis server once within the singleton. `getInstance()` returns the connection.

But I've noticed that my singleton is created once per API route. Does NextJS do something to cause this to happen?

How can I create 1 instance of a Redis connection in a NextJS app, just for the API routes held inside of `pages/api`? I'm using ioredis library.

Comment: Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variables. Below setup for redis should work for nextJS using redis cloud free instance which has max 30 connections available in free plan.

Code:

```
import * as redis from 'redis';

const REDIS_USERNAME = process.env.REDIS_USERNAME;
const REDIS_PASSWORD = process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD;
const REDIS_HOST = process.env.REDIS_HOST;
const REDIS_PORT = process.env.REDIS_PORT;

let redisClient;
let redisClientPromise;

if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    if (!global._redisClientPromise) {
        redisClient = redis.createClient({
            url: `redis://${REDIS_USERNAME}:${REDIS_PASSWORD}@${REDIS_HOST}:${REDIS_PORT}`
        });
        redisClient.connect().then(() => {
            console.info(
                `NextJS Redis client connected..`
            );
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(`[ERROR] Couldn't connect to Redis client: ${error}`);
        });
        global._redisClientPromise = redisClient;
    }
    redisClientPromise = global._redisClientPromise
} else {
    redisClient = redis.createClient({
        url: `redis://${REDIS_USERNAME}:${REDIS_PASSWORD}@${REDIS_HOST}:${REDIS_PORT}`
    });
    redisClient.connect().then(() => {
        console.info(
            `NextJS Redis client connected..`
        );
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(`[ERROR] Couldn't connect to Redis client: ${error}`);
    });
    redisClientPromise = redisClient;
}

export default redisClientPromise;
```